# How do I make my ASP.net control perform a postback?

Tags: asp.net, controls

I'm writing my first ASP.net control.  I would like to know to know how to make the control postback when the user clicks something (but in general, I want to know how to make arbitrary events make the control postback).

**Update** Thanks for the answer.  However, upon more Googling, it sounds like I'm supposed to make my control call a JavaScript function called __doPostBack.  It says that I'm supposed to pass __doPostBack the UniqueID of the control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You implement [IPostBackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx).  The linked MSDN page includes a code example.